# Protocol error when mounting in virtual machine

Tags: mount, virtualbox

When running the following command in an Ubuntu 14.04 VM in a 14.04 host, I get a `mount: protocol error`

```
mount -t vboxsf -o uid=1000,gid=1000 updatable /opt/apps/directory/updatable
```

Guest additions are correct, updatable is currently mounted (according to mount) on `/media/sf_updatable`, I've rebooted so everything should be in sync. I've tried lots of things but I don't know what the protocol error means or what I'm looking to solve.